# Set JQuery propeties to Image folder path in img src tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question background:**

I'm trying to set two propeties of a JQuery function to an `img src`  who's images are stored in the `Images` folder of my MVC site.

**The Issue:**

The following code shows the properties `nextText` and `prevText` being set to a left and right .jpg I have in the `Images` folder of my site:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        controls: true,
        pager: false,
        nextText: '<img src="~/Images/rightArrow.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>',
        prevText: '<img src="~/Images/leftArrow.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>'
    });
```

Currently the above produces a **broken Image** on my page. Can I use the `~` to get the relative path on an `img src` tag? If I supply an external image url from Google in the `img src` then that works.

How can i correctly set the `nextText` and `prevText` properties so they use an Image in the `Images` folder on my site?

Comment: use '.' instead of '~'

Comment: @Ryuk87 This dosent seem to work either. When I use `.` I cannot see the `Images` folder as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a baseUrl in script tag in your layout page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
</script>
```

and use that in your script like below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        controls: true,
        pager: false,
        nextText: '<img src="'+baseUrl +'Images/rightArrow.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>',
        prevText: '<img src="'+baseUrl +'Images/leftArrow.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>'
    });
```

This will work even after deployment. I had same problem and I use this way to solve this problem.